# Differences with WordPress function.php and footer custom linking?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, slick.js

A different way of plugging custom javascript code with **function.php** in WordPress and custom scripting inside the **footer** in **html**?

There's a difference, I don't know why?

Actually, the problem is related to init Slick Slider Carousel inside WordPress custom theme.

**WordPress version 5.5.2**

The first way, classic plugging custom script from **function.php**, but the part related to Slick Carousel (in custom js) not started while all other parts inside custom js they work without problems and errors.

Included jQuery and Slick Carousel CDN's

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-slider', 'https://unpkg.com/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js' );
```

Try to include custom js from **function.php**

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/main.js');
```

Slick Carousel doesn't work?

On a different way, where I commented script part above and replaced the code with classic scripting in **footer.php** with classic:

```html
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/main.js"></script>
```

Slick works perfectly and other parts too. Without errors again.

No errors and warnings in both cases.

Comment: Maybe wp_enqueue_script() inserts JS at different place on page. Compare page source in those 2 cases to see where is the difference.

Comment: @MilanG, I have above this custom js one more little custom, and they are both linked in the same way, first has no problem, second has only with Slick carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Custom JavaScript, where is initiate Slick Carousel must be called in the footer of WordPress page.
In this case, use **true** parameter inside **wp_enqueue_script** :

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri(). 'your-custom-js','','',true);
```

> wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool **$in_footer = false** )

[Read more about **wp_enqueue_script** here.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)